# Stored procedure error::Invalid object name..Need help

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

fetching data from 2 tables in one Stored Proceure..what's wrong with the SP below ?

Its giving error as "Msg 208, Level 16, State 6, Procedure sp_GetID, Line 9
Invalid object name 'Admin.sp_GetID'."

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetID  
(
 @ID int  
)
AS  
BEGIN  


 SELECT ID FROM Language WHERE ID=@ID  

END
```

**I am altering a previously made procedure...All I changed was ..I added the second SELECt statment...just that...otherwise SP was executing**

Comment: Why have you prefixed the storeproc with 'sp_'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the procedure doesn't exist.  Try changing `ALTER` to `CREATE`.

Comment: I am altering a previously made procedure...All I changed was ..I added the second SELECt statment...just that...otherwise SP was executing

Comment: Just asking, but are you sure you are executing this in the context of the correct database?

Comment: @Serenity, just to make sure, if you thought the sp already existed, be sure you didn't accidentally create it in a different database, like 'master'.

Answer (score 0):

I am hearing this error for the first time please remove [Admin] from [Admin].[sp_GetTelerikLanguageCodeAdminID] in the stored procedure name and execute. I hope it will work i have seen only [dbo] at that place

Comment: No I cant change that, ALL SPs in the DB have been named like this only..Admin being the Schema name here